# Dritthalbtausend?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, numbers

Ein Buch von Lüneburg über die Geschichte der Mathematik heißt:

> Von Zahlen und Größen: Dritthalbtausend Jahre Theorie und Praxis.

Wieviel ist *Dritthalbtausend* und wie üblich ist dieser Ausdruck?

Comment: Ich vermute stark, dass hier absichtlich ein archaisches Zahlwort verwendet wird, um eine Art selbstreferentiellen Witz zu machen.

Comment: Der Begriff ist vollkommen ungebräuchlich. Ich hätte vermutet, dass es 1.500 Jahre sind. In Halbtausendjahren gerechnet, drei.

Comment: @userunknown: Du irrst dich aber. Œlrim hat die richtige Antwort gefunden und gepostet: Dritthalb = 2,5, also eine Hälfte weniger als 3. (Auf dem halben Weg zur Drei)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Hatte ich längst gelesen. Deswegen 'Ich hätte vermutet' und nicht 'Ich vermute'. Ich behaupte nur, dass das fast niemand weiß und nicht eben eine Mehrheit durch eigenes Grübeln auf 2,5k kommt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laut dem [Grimm-Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GD04924#XGD04924) hat *drittehalb* die Bedeutung *zwei und ein halbes*, das Prinzip dürfte ähnlich wie bei der Uhrzeit sein (*halb drei* = 2:30 Uhr). Demnach sind Dritthalbtausend Jahre 2500 Jahre.

Diese Ausdruckweise scheint nur vereinzelt um das 15. Jahrhundert verwendet worden zu sein. Heute würde sie kaum noch verstanden werden. Der Autor des Mathematikbuches hat das offenbar bewusst als Stilmittel oder Witz gewählt.

Comment: Interessant. Eine weitere Referenz zu dritthalb; ein Zitat von Jean Paul aus "Hesperus oder 45 Hundposttage": "`Der Mensch hat dritthalb Minuten; eine zu lächeln, eine zu seufzen, und eine halbe zu lieben; denn mitten in dieser Minute stirbt er.`" ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesperus_oder_45_Hundposttage), [aphorismen.de](http://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/63728))

Comment: "Anderthalb" ist übrigens nach dem gleichen Prinzip
gebildet. "Ander" wurde nämlich bis ins 17. Jahrhundert - wie heute noch in den skandinavischen Sprachen - als Ordinalzahl zu "zwei" verwendet ("der andere" = "der zweite"). "Anderthalb" bedeutet also eigentlich "zweithalb" (= "Einer
und der Zweite zur Hälfte").

Answer (score 5):

According to the *Grimms DWb* it means: “of the third only half.” I.e. “One, two, but of the third only half.”

The word is used in KHM 1815 # 45 "*The Beautiful Katrinelies and Pif, Paf, Poltrie.*" »*Schön Katrinelje, wie viel hast du an Brautschatz?« – »Vierzehn Pfennige baares Geld, **drittehalb** Groschen Schuld, ein halb Pfund Hutzeln, eine Hand voll Prutzeln, eine Hand voll Wurzeln*,"

It is also used by Martin Luther in his Bible. It happens to be one dimension of the Arc of the Covenant.

[image]From: Luther Bible, 1797, pg. 85.

There is a similar word “viertehalb” which  means three and a half, not four and a half. The *Grimms DWb* defines “viertehalb” as: “three and a half, the first, second, third whole, the fourth half.” The *DWb* also lists examples of “drittehalb” from the Bible where it describes the size of the Ark of the Covenant where the Ten Commandments are said to have been placed. From the Luther Bible 2 Moses 25, 10: “10 Macht eine Lade aus Akazienholz; dritthalb Ellen soll die Länge sein, anderthalb Ellen die Breite und anderthalb Ellen die Höhe.”In the King James version Exodus 25, 10: “10 And they shall make an ark of shittim wood: two cubits and a half shall be the length thereof, and a cubit and a half the breadth thereof, and a cubit and a half the height thereof.”

Note: The Bible quotes are from Biblegateway.com. The wood is written there as “Akazienholz,” but as can be seen above, the actual word in this edition of the Luther Bible is “Förenholz.” Any electronic source should be checked and compared to an image of the original. All too often, differences exist.

The second example listed in the DWb is from the Luther Bible 2 Moses 37, 1 which is: “*37 Und Bezaleel machte die Lade von Akazienholz, **dritthalb** Ellen lang, anderthalb Ellen breit und hoch,*” Exodus 37, 1 in the King James version is: “*37 And Bezaleel made the ark of shittim wood: **two cubits and a half** was the length of it, and a cubit and a half the breadth of it, and a cubit and a half the height of it:*” Of the translators who write it as “cubits” in the Bible, all write it as “**two and a half,**” none write it as “three and a half.”  Clearly “drittehalb” is “two and a half,” but not all translators of Grimm agree.

Grimm KHM 2 ½ Translators -

The 1853 Addey ed. writes is as ”*fourteen pennies in bare money, **two and a half** farthings owing to me.*”

Manheim in his 1977 edition writes it as: “*Fourteen pfennigs in cash, **two and a half** groschen in debts*.”

Grimm KHM 3 ½ Translators -

Hunt, in her 1884 edition writes it as: “*Fourteen farthings in ready money, **three and a half** groschen owing to me.*”

Zipes in his 1987 ed writes it as: “*Fourteen pennies in cash, **three and a half** groschen that are owed to me.*”

Zipes in his 2014 ed writes it as: “*Fourteen pennies in cash, **three and a half** coins that are owed to me.*”

The unknown translator of the Addey edition and Manheim translate the word correctly as 2 ½; Hunt, and Zipes in both his 1987 and 2014 editions, write it as 3 ½.